# How to use "back" hardware button in Corona?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I want to cause a pause-menu scene when I touch back button located on the bottom panel (with "home", "menu") but I don't understand how to do it. This can be implemented in Corona SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add a listener for `key` events to the Runtime in the scenes that should respond to key events.  This is **essential** for the back key; without it, the system will back out of (i.e. exit) the app.  Assuming a `scene` object, you could do:

```
function scene:key(event)

    if ( event.keyName == "back" ) then

          -- handle the back key press however you choose
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "key", scene )
```

For more information about `key` events, see [the Corona documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/key/index.html).

As for the “pause menu scene”, you probably want to use an [overlay](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/showOverlay.html).  From the documentation on `composer.showOverlay()`:

> This function loads an overlay scene above the currently active scene (the parent scene), leaving the parent scene intact.
>   When an overlay is shown, an overlay-specific scene event parameter, event.parent, will be dispatched to the overlay scene.
>
> This parameter provides you with a reference to the parent scene object so that you may call functions/methods within it.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use overlay but many thanks for the info about the keys.

Comment: My pleasure @NekoDev.  Please mark the question as answered.